# Balancing the requirement to earn Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

In the current setting, the number of unique IPs required by Announcer, Boosters, and Publicist is 25, 300, and 1000 respectively.  In terms of times, Boosters is 12X as many as Announcer, but Publicist is just 3.3X as many as Booster.

I am wondering if the gap between Booster and Announcer is too large and thinking about whether an equal ratio gap makes sense? Given 25 for Announcer and 1000 for Publicist, Publicist is 40X as many as Announcer, would Booster requiring less than sqrt(40X) as many as Announcer makes more sense?  For example, 125? (in this case Booster:Announcer = 5, Publicist:Booster = 8?).

Another indicator, up to date, we have 14663 ppl earned Announcer, 768 ppl earned Booster, and 307 ppl learned Publicist.  This means nearly 40% of ppl earned Booster eventually earned publicist, but only 5% of Announcer who is able to earn Booster.

Comment: Don't be too afraid of duplicates; dupes serve as sign-posts so that others that think of a problem in the same terms as you can find their way to the original as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you for your encouragement, I know that in the SO faq, but people here sometimes seems unfriendly on dupes :(

Comment: Why is the gap too large?

Comment: I think is if moving from Announcer to Booster is harder than moving from Booster to Publicist, then the gap between Announcer and Booster is considered too large ...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I have updated the post and include more information.

Comment: +1. Just note that square root is not the right median here because of the "viral" effect. But this just makes your point stronger.

Comment: @djechlin: Thank you, that's why I said less than sqrt :)

Comment: Gold badges are supposed to be hard to earn

Comment: @Hugo Yes, it is. But the current design says it's nearly has hard as silver.  I never want to adjust for the Gold one, but the silver one.